# How Asynchronous method invocation pattern in c# works and implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am moving lots of code loosely based on [asynchronous method invocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_method_invocation). How is it typically implemented (preferably in production)?

- How does it work?
- How is it used?
- How is it implemented?

Comment: You really need to be more specific. That's far too broad of a question.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=Asynchronous+method+invocation+pattern

Answer (score 4):

The pattern is usually as follows:

- You have a `BeginXXX` method which receives all in and `ref` arguments plus a [`AsyncCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx) delegate (may be null) and a state object reference (may also be null) and returns an [`IAsyncResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx). This method is invoked to start the call, and it returns more or less immediately.
- Then you have a `EndXXX` method which takes the `IAsyncResult` returned by the `BeginXXX` operation plus any `ref` and `out` arguments which is invoked when the call is to be completed (either after callback, waiting on [event in the `IAsyncResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.asyncwaithandle.aspx) or by blocking). The `EndXXX` will return the method result (if not a void method) or throw an exception (if the method threw an exception).

Have a look at the Stream class or on any delegate, they provide you with examples of those signatures. Also, there is a complete [description of async calls on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228975.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is usually implemented via .NET's [IOCompletion port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa365198). This allows a small pool of threads to service many IO operations completing, with the `BeginX` calling the appropriate Win32 API to initiate an asynchronous operation, the implementation of IAsyncResult holding any state (associated with the underlying operation via the [`OVERLAPPED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684342) instance), and `EndX` picking up the result.

The details (and the other approaches) vary widely depending on the resource in question.